# WPF DataGrid - Iterating through rows and accessing control in template column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I come from an ASP.NET background, and I've been tasked with maintaining a WPF project, so it's quite a learning curve.

I have a DataGrid with the following XAML

```
<DataGrid Name="StockGV" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Scanned" IsReadOnly="true">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Name="StatusImage" Source="tick.png"></Image>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PalletScanned}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="StatusImage" Property="Source" Value="cross.png"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pallet Number" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding PalletNumber}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Quantity}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="true">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xctk:IntegerUpDown HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="integerUpDown1" Maximum="{Binding Quantity}" Minimum="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding Quantity, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PalletScanned}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="integerUpDown1" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The user updates the last field (the IntegerUpDown control), and then they click a 'Save' button below the grid. I need this to iterate through each row, get the value of the IntegerUpDown control and save this to the DB. If this was ASP.NET, I'd do something like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
     long pk = (long)gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
     int value = (int)((IntegerUpDown)row.FindControl("integerUpDown1")).Value;
     //Save to DB
}
```

How would I do this in WPF? Note if it helps, the DataGrid is bound to an anonymous type

Answer (score 5):

Wow that is not like its meant to be :)

You should normally bind the `DataGrid` to an `ItemsSource` of Type T. Inside the Columns you should bind to properties of your Type T.

Every change on your IntegerUpDown `Control` is then represented in the underlying Collection.

To access this value later in your `ViewModel` you can just query the `Collection` with Linq to get the Values.

You already got this code in your Control:

```
Value="{Binding Quantity, Mode=OneWay}"
```

So you can access the Quantity property to get the value you want.

Remember:
If the User should be able to change the Quantity `Property`, the `Binding` has to be `Mode=TwoWay` and there needs to be a public setter for this Property too.

Comment: Don't forget the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Yea true, thanks for that. I totally forgot to mention it! :)